# Is it possible to create facebook page tab that let users upload photos to one specific page album?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, file-upload, facebook-page, facebook-tabs

one question.

I've a facebook page that represents a product.
I've added some tabs in the page, beside About, Likes, Photos, Videos, Notes... to explain better my product functionalities.

I would like to have a tab with a photo uploader, to let any user who liked my page to add photos to a specific Photo Album in my Photos section.

I was using the application [Static HTML Plus](https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_plus/) to add static HTML into my tab. But for the tab that upload photos, this application is not what i need. Is there a way to make a tab refer to another script, that could be easily reached throuhg an URL in my server. Or are there any outher solutions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users can only post photos to the page feed, but not in albums. You need a page token to do this.

Create a long living token with the needed permissions and let your app upload the photo. You can link the user in the photo-message by using his id.

Comment: I created an application, inserted as a page tab on the facebook page of the product, and that page tab refers to a url that ends up on my server, there i will manage the upload and the photo posting.

Comment: And on your server you authenticate the user and he uploads the photo. User is done, photo goes to upload class, where you have to start another facebooksession using your long living token and finally upload the photo to your album.
That way you can also save statistics like who posted, when did he post. Or you can block more than one photo per user, for contests or whatever.